# What is the correct formula for Parseval's identity?

Tags: parsevals-identity

Looking for a quick validation here:

We have a periodic function $f(t)$ with a period of $T$ that satisfies Dirichlet's conditions. Which of the following 2 formulas is correct ?

My book (not professor's):

$$\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}f(t)^2dt = \frac{a_0^2}{4} + \frac{1}{2}*\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n^2+b_n^2)$$

My professor's slides:

$$\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}f(t)^2dt = {a_0^2} + \frac{1}{2}*\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n^2+b_n^2)$$

Which of these 2 is the correct one?

Comment: It depends on how $a_0$ is defined.

Comment: @MarkViola Oh you're absolutely right! I didn't observe that $a_0$ had different definitions.

Comment: @MarkViola you mean whether the Fourier series is defined as complex exponential or as a trigonometric series ?

Comment: @Physor No, that's not what I meant.